# Is there such a thing as a run-on-sentence in Chinese?

Tags: grammar, writing

In Chinese articles I often find these long, never-ending, main-point-less sentences.

For instance check out these three sentence-paragraphs from [this news article ("请给90后创业者多一些宽容")](http://zhangjiangjian.baijia.baidu.com/article/38219)

> 尽管随后余佳文在微博上专门发文针对知呼上对其学历、融资额、用户数据等等质疑做了相应回应，但是从舆论上依然负面不断，尤其是与之前马佳佳的炒作放在一起，总的来说给人一种90后创业者“不靠谱”的感觉。
>
> 与很多创业项目不同的是，这个被推到风口浪尖的超级课程表团队基本都是出身草根的90后，没有显赫的背景、华丽的学历、光鲜的职业履历，白手起家硬生生从零开始做到成功拿下阿里的风险投资，不管盈利多少、用户多少、融资多少，能走得到这个阶段当属不易。
>
> 如果真有错，就错在这位90后CEO太过高调，打破了华南地区创业者一向低调务实的传统，更是广东地区的创业者罕有的登上了中国互联网圈子的头条，之前的马佳佳、郝畅、雕爷的案例基本都诞生于京城，很少有外地的案例引起主流互联网圈子的关注。

Is this just *bad* writing, or is there no such thing as a run on sentence in Chinese?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this is some quite advanced writing.

And no, there's no such a thing as run-on sentence in Chinese. At least not exactly as in English.

The structure used in this article is called 排比(parallelism, http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%8E%92%E6%AF%94). Parallelism is "a balance within one or more sentences of similar phrases or clauses that have the same grammatical structure."

If you look carefully, you can identify multiple groups of phrases with similar pattern describing a common subjective/objective:

> 这个被推到风口浪尖的超级课程表团队基本都是出身草根的90后，没有
>
> - 显赫的背景、
> - 华丽的学历、
> - 光鲜的职业履历，
>
> 白手起家硬生生从零开始做到成功拿下阿里的风险投资，不管
>
> - 盈利多少、
> - 用户多少、
> - 融资多少，
>
> 能走得到这个阶段当属不易。

You should also consider it phonetically. This kind of structures are usually used in a speech or a debate. Because of those similar structures, when you say it out loud, you'll get nice rhythm, stronger/firmer tone and look more confident in your content in front of your listeners. It helps with getting your ideas across or intimidating your opponents.

People are always looking for patterns in stuff (even when it's not there). Just give it to them.

Answer (score 1):

This is really perfect writing.

尽管随后余佳文在微博上专门发文针对知呼上对其学历、融资额、用户数据等等质疑做了相应回应，但是从舆论上(余佳文)依然负面不断，尤其是与之前马佳佳的炒作放在一起，总的来说（余佳文）给人一种90后创业者“不靠谱”的感觉。

You can see the whole sentences has one common subject-(余佳文). And you can find associated words are used to combine the short sentences.

I know you confused why not divide them into two part at the beginning of 尤其. But if you analysis as follow you may understand.

Firstly,尽管随后余佳文在微博上专门发文针对知呼上对其学历、融资额、用户数据等等质疑做了相应回应，但是从舆论上(余佳文)依然负面不断. It is a complete sentence。

Then,尤其是与之前马佳佳的炒作放在一起. You can find there is no subject. It should be：
尤其是 (余佳文负面不断这件事) **与** 之前马佳佳的炒作放在一起. So, the first part cannot be end. It be used as subject of second part.

Finally, 尤其是(余佳文负面不断这件事)与之前马佳佳的炒作放在一起，总的来说给人一种90后创业者“不靠谱”的感觉。 The structure "Combined with xxx, I think it is not a good idea."

Now, how do you think about that. I have to say, it is really professional writing. In China, most student in university cannot reach this level. So, don't care about that.

Comment: In final part, 总的来说(余佳文)给人一种90后创业者“不靠谱”的感觉。余佳文is the subject share with first part.

Comment: So is there such a thing as a run-on or not then...?

Comment: For these three sentences, they are not run-on sentences. They are professional and perfect writing which can be found in some magazines about IT, finance or business.

Comment: I will show you about division of these three sentences.
1.尽管随后在微博上专门发文针对知呼上对其学历、融资额、用户数据等等质疑做了相应回应，但是从舆论上,（余佳文）依然负面不断。尤其是这些负面新闻与之前马佳佳的炒作放在一起，总的来说，（余佳文）给人一种90后创业者“不靠谱”的感觉。

2.与很多创业项目不同的是，这个被推到风口浪尖的超级课程表团队基本都是出身草根的90后，没有显赫的背景、华丽的学历、光鲜的职业履历，白手起家硬生生从零开始做到成功拿下阿里的风险投资。不管盈利多少、用户多少、融资多少，（这个团队）能走得到这个阶段当属不易。

3.如果真有错，就错在这位90后CEO太过高调。（余佳文）打破了华南地区创业者一向低调务实的传统，更是广东地区的创业者罕有的登上了中国互联网圈子的头条。之前的马佳佳、郝畅、雕爷的案例基本都诞生于京城，很少有外地的案例（像余佳文这样）引起主流互联网圈子的关注。

Answer (score -1):

Well,it contains a lot of information in one sentence.In my view,the weakness of this article is paragraphing.The author tried to gather the information in one sentence regardless of paragraph.